# Find out what functions exists inside an object

Tags: javascript, console.log, extjs6, console.dir

I have written code like in below mentioned fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d3r

You can see at the end of the code `record.get('text')`.

How to find the functions which I can use from inside an object?

I tried console.dir in chrome and saw the same output as console.log.

Is there any other way to see all functions I can use?

Comment: You mean [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/z5q3q1x7/)? I get something like `["initConfig", "self", "HasListeners", "getRefItems", ...`.

Comment: @DaveChen - Kid of. console.dir shows output in different manner.

Answer (score -1):

You could try iterating through the properties of the object:

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```